# ManagedBeans for different components in JSF

Tags: java, spring, jsf, jsf-2

I have a question regarding usage of ManagedBeans in application.

I have a page which as different JSP components like autoComplete, selectOneMenu, textarea, inputFields, datatable etc.

I am using separate Service classes and DAO's for these components as Entity classes are different for these.

When it comes to ManagedBeans should I use one ManagedBean for all compoenents for one page or different ManagedBean for different components?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the components on a single page will most likely be highly coupled, there is no real benefit for using more than one managedbean. However if one part of the bean is highly repeated in several pages you might consider refactoring it into a [Composite Component](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf/jsf_composite_components.htm).

Comment: Any performance issues if I use one ManagedBean for multiple components or if I use multiple ManagedBean for multiple components? Which is the best practice?

Comment: Unless you are doing high cost operations during the creation of a ManagedBean (i.e. in a method annotated with `@PostConstruct`) there shouldn't be any performance related problems for using multiple beans, however like I said there is no benefit (that I know of) for doing that as well.

Comment: I do have `@PostConstruct` in ManagedBeans, so better to have one or?

Comment: It is just a hook to execute some code while the bean is created, my point was if you use more than one bean in a page, while the page is being rendered all of those PostConstructs will execute and if you are doing some heavy work there, that might cause some performance problems.

Comment: You can also say that you can use `@SessionScoped` and `@ApplicationScoped` managed beans in more than 1 pages for different functionalities like user preferences or application language (session data) or dropdownlist data (application scope).